# How Update one table row with combare with the other polygon table using their geom in SQL Server

Tags: postgresql, sql, sql-server

a-> points
b -> Polygon

i want to update city trow in table a with compare b of geom in SQL server

this is the PostgreSQL Query

```
update a set city=b.name from b where st_contains(b.the_geom, a.the_geom)
```

how convert this to sql server or how update city trow in table a, on SQL server?

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server the statement should look like this:

```
Update a set CITY = b.NAME from b where (b.the_geom.STContains(a.the_geom) = 1)
```

Notice that [STContains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933904.aspx) is a method on the Geometry instance that takes another geometry instance as input.

Also notice that the method is case sensitive.